# How can I learn fully/more about the various ways Americans use the phrase "I guess" nowadays?

Tags: phrase-usage, american-english

I wanna learn like all about it. Its intonation, the context, the volume of voice, the pitch, etc.

Because I don' think any online dictionary can probably help you with that. So do you guys have any good sources/resources recommendations for me or something like that? Because I'm really eager to learn much more about it you know.

Comment: For written uses, you could search at Google books for the phrase in quotes.

Comment: I'm actually more interested in its spoken uses, but thank you tho!

Answer (score 1):

1. [Playphrase.me](https://www.playphrase.me/#/search?q=I%20guess) is a website that will play clips of movies based on a specific phrase! I am not associated with it, just seems really cool.
2. Other than that I might suggest asking american internet-friends to send you audio recordings of them saying 'I guess.' Maybe you can find a facebook group or subreddit that reads requests.

*(Ps I have said 'I guess' to myself so many times now haha.)*

Comment: Thank you, i really appreciated! I guess the second suggestion will be more useful tho. I think in the end the best way to grasp it far better is to really have an actual conversation with Am.E native speakers.